# Why does my (json) image go outside the border/container even with max-width set to 100%?

Tags: javascript, css, json, fetch

I'm using an API call to get the image info. The image I get back and want to display to the dom comes in the form of a `<figure>` json data. The API json data has set widths, which I notice I can change in CSS when I set a specific width to it. But what if I want it to grow or shrink with the container? I should be able to setting the `max-width` to 100%, but the images all go outside the container in mobile size. Also, they dont get larger when I increase the size of the screen, they stay at the same size.

JSON Data returned:

```
<figure data-align="right" data-img-src="https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/8338/1349827-popeye_cabinet.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-1349827" data-size="small" data-ratio="1.3333333333333" data-width="375" data-embed-type="image" style="width: 375px"><a class="fluid-height" style="padding-bottom:133.3%" href="https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/8338/1349827-popeye_cabinet.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-1349827"><img alt=" Original Arcade Cabinet" src="https://giantbomb1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/0/8338/1349827-popeye_cabinet.jpg" srcset="https://giantbomb1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/0/8338/1349827-popeye_cabinet.jpg 375w" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 480px" data-width="480"></a><figcaption> Original Arcade Cabinet</figcaption></figure>
```

My CSS:

```
figure {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

figure img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Classic Arcade Game Info</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P|Raleway|Amatic+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="header">

            <a name="top"></a>

            <div class="title">
                <img src=images/jacob.jpg class="jacobLogo" alt="cartoon Jacob head">
                <h1> Classic Arcade Game Info</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="headInfo">
                <p>Search for you favorite Arcade Game below to recieve information about the game and videos!</p>
            </div>

            <form>
                <div class="searchSection">
                    <input class="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Donkey Kong" required>
                </div> 
                <div class="buttonSection">
                    <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Search">
                </div>  
            </form>

        </header>

        <main class="main">

            <div class="arrow hidden">
                <a href="#top"><img class="arrowImage" src="images/boxArrow.jpg"><a href="#top"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="loading">
                <section class="loadingMessage"></section>
            </div>

            <div class="errors">
                <section class="errorMessage"></section>
            </div>

            <div class="infoContainer hidden">
                <section class="infoResults hidden info"></section>
            </div>

            <div class="tubeContainer hidden">
                <section class="tubeResults hidden tube">
                    <input class="youTubeLogo" type="image" src="images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube Logo">
                    <section class="tubeList"></section>
                </section> 
            </div>

        </main>

        <footer class="footer">

            <p>Another fun site created by Jacob Ashley</p>

        </footer>

        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your html code as well

Comment: add a box sizing to your img styles `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: HTML Provided now.
```box-sizing: border-box;``` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML provided doesn't really correlate with the image you shared. I'm sure this is because a call happens from your script.js and one of these divs is replaced with the json figure tag.

However, the figure code you provided that's returned from the api has width declared in a style tag to override this in your front end you'll need to use !important.

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 40px;
}
figure {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% !important;
}

figure img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/k7Lg1tc3/19/) approximating what I assume your layout is like with the returned image.